# Django. Order by filtered backward related field

Tags: python, django

I have such models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    value = models.FloatField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

I need to sort `Parent` instances by children values, but consider only child with defined name.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much do it as you describe:

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__name='defined name').order_by('child__value')
```

Comment: 1. Parent does not have field `child` only `children`
2. If you use `children` instead - you will filter parents witch have child with defined name and then sort by all children, not child with with defined name.

Comment: 1 is true, but 2 is not. Only one JOIN is performed, so the ORDER BY will sort by the filtered values.